# How to generate sound signal through a GPIO pin on BeagleBone

Tags: python, audio, beagleboard

I am looking for pointers/tips on how to generate a synthesized sound signal on the BeagleBone akin to watch the tone() function would return on a Arduinos. Ultimately, I'd like to connect a piezo or a speaker on a GPIO pin and hear a sound wave out of it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve this question on the Beaglebone using Python and [PyBBIO](https://github.com/alexanderhiam/PyBBIO):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Circuit:
# * A Piezo is connected to pin 12 on header P8.        - GPIO1_12
# * A LED is connected to pin 14 on header P8.          - GPIO0_26
# * A button is connected to pin 45 on header P8.       - GPIO2_6
#   Use a pull-down resistor (around 10K ohms) between pin 45 and ground. 
#       3.3v for the other side of the button can be taken from pins 3 or 4 
#       on header P9. Warning: Do not allow 5V to go into the GPIO pins.
# * GND - pin 1 or 2, header P9.

def setup(): # this function will run once, on startup
    pinMode(PIEZO, OUTPUT) # set up pin 12 on header P8 as an output - Piezo
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT) # set up pin 14 on header P8 as an output - LED
    pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT) # set up pin 45 on header P8 as an input - Button

def loop(): # this function will run repeatedly, until user hits CTRL+C
    if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH): 
        # was the button pressed? (is 3.3v making it HIGH?) then do:
            buzz()
    delay(10) # don't "peg" the processor checking pin

def delay(j):  #need to overwrite delay() otherwise, it's too slow
    for k in range(1,j):
            pass

def buzz():    #this is what makes the piezo buzz - a series of pulses
               # the shorter the delay between HIGH and LOW, the higher the pitch
    limit = 500     # change this value as needed; 
                    # consider using a potentiometer to set the value
    for j in range(1, limit):
            digitalWrite(PIEZO, HIGH)
            delay(j)
            digitalWrite(PIEZO, LOW)
            delay(j)
            if j==limit/2:
                    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH)
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW) # turn it off

run(setup, loop)
```

Answer (score 1):

The GPIO pins of the AM3359 are low-voltage and with insufficient driver strength to directly drive any kind of transducer.  You would need to build a small circuit with a op-amp, transistor or FET to do this.

Once you've done this, you'd simply set up a timer loop to change the state of the GPIO line at the required frequency.

By far the quickest and easiest way of getting audio from this board is with a USB Audio interface.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this page](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/GPIO_Driver_Guide). From userland (e.g. python) you can use set a pin to high or low by writing to the correct `sysfs` file in `/sys/class/gpio`.